# How to do JWT Bearer API security for .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, .net-4.7.2

I have an existing .net application - 4.7.2, doesn't use core. I need to look how to write code for JWT Bearer API security for .net framework 4.7.2 similar to -

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "Authority";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = "api";
            });
```

Any help would be really appreciated?